# how to import csv file into mongodb in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, csv, eclipselink

I'm using EclipseLink as API for mongodb. I need to update my database each time from given csv files.
Is there any way to import a CSV file into MongoDB with java?
or is it possible to execute a raw mongo command like this in java enviroment?

```
mongoimport --db users --collection contacts --type csv --file /opt/backups/contacts.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mongoimport --db users --collection contacts --type csv --headerline --file /opt/backups/contacts.csv
```

`--collection` parameter is optional. If it is not passed, a collection with *filename* (without extension) will be created. In this case, the collection name will be "contacts".

`--headerline` parameter is optional. Specifying `--headerline` instructs `mongoimport` to determine the name of the fields using the first line in the CSV file.

Additionally, `--ignoreBlanks` can be specified to ignore blank fields in CSV.

More information can be found in `mongoimport` documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/#human-intelligible-exports).

Comment: thanks Manish. But I need to know how to import csv or run that command in my Java code

Comment: This command can be executed just like any other executable file can be executed through java. You can use `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime.exec()` for this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way for mongoimport in Java Driver.

Try `Runtime.exec()`. Sample code:

```
  Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
  Process p = null;
  String command = "mongoimport --db users --collection contacts --type csv --file /opt/backups/contacts.csv";
  try {
   p = r.exec(command);
   System.out.println("Reading csv into Database");

  } catch (Exception e){
   System.out.println("Error executing " + command + e.toString());
  }
```

Check out this [blog](http://javamongodb.blogspot.in/2013/07/loading-up-data.html) for more details.