# how to import JSON file into mongodb in Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala

I need to update my MongoDB database each time from given JSON files. Is there any way to import a JSON file into MongoDB with Scala? or is it possible to **execute** a raw mongo command like this in Scala environment?

```
mongoimport --db issue --collection customer --type json --file /home/lastvalue/part-00000.json
```

In Java we can do like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34491269/8641022) but I need to implement it in Scala. Where I will get to import the libraries of this classes?

Comment: What have you tried by yourself?

Answer (score 1):

When writing Scala, you can use any Java library, including the `Process` library that your link refers to.

This will allow you to run the `mongoimport` command in a process spawned from your Scala code. If you're looking for a solution entirely written in Scala, you should use the [mongo-scala-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver). The documentation includes a [complete example](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver/blob/master/examples/scripts/mongoimport.scala) to mimic mongoimport's functionalities.